# How to discard local changes in Android Studio GUI?

Tags: android, git

I want to discard the local changes I made in an Android Studio project.

I tried to perform a pull, the GUI gives me 5 options, which option should I choose?

- Octopus
- Ours
- Subtree
- Recursive
- Resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You originally asked which strategy argument to use with `git pull` to discard your own work (there is a pending edit that will change the question, if the edit is approved).  The answer is:  None.

Don't use `git pull` at all.  Run `git fetch` first:

```
git fetch origin
```

This brings over all the new stuff from the other Git you have your Git calling "origin".

Now that you have everything they have, simply stop using what you have been using, and switch to theirs:

```
git reset --hard origin/master   # assuming you're on your "master"
```

You may also want to use `git clean -fdx` to remove build artifacts, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio do the following:

-Open the **Version Control** tool window Alt+9 and switch to the **Log** tab.

-Select the recent commit and right click on it than select **Reset Current Branch to Here**.

-A Git Reset popup will open -> select **Hard** -> click **Reset**

Answer (score 2):

In Android studio do the following:

Go to VCS -> Git -> Reset HEAD

Change Reset type to hard